# react-router v4 Link doesn't work in karma test runner

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I would like to write some specs to test my current routing in my app. I use karma to run my specs and mocha as test framework. Everything works fine until I click on some `<Link />` component. Event onclick launched but it doesn't trigger re-rendering my components and, hence, nothing changes (app doesn't render new `<Match />` routers). My current code:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
'use strict';
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Match, Redirect } from 'react-router';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
import axios from 'axios';
import Main_Store from '../../main.store';
import Base from '../../components/base.component';

describe.only('--Routing--', () => {
   let main_store, wrap;
   beforeEach(() => {
      main_store = new Main_Store();
      wrap = mount(
         <MemoryRouter initialIndex={1} initialEntries={['/', '/kit']}>
            <Match pattern={'/:district'} render={(props) => {
                  console.log('trigger match');
                  return <Base {...props} main_store={main_store} />
               }
            } />
         </MemoryRouter>
      );
   });

   describe('click on link', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
         wrap.find('Link').findWhere(n => n.prop('to') === '/kit/user-1/type-created').simulate('click');
      });

      it('render Profile Bar', () => {
         console.log('current html', wrap.html())
         expect(wrap.find('.personSidebar')).to.have.length(1);
      });
   });
});
```

current event log

1. After mount component recognize that it match current pathname.
2. Component is rendered first time.
3. onClick event on is fired

and there is nothing else. In my browser i receive 1 and 2 point again which means that component tree is re-rendered after click on Link. But in my test inv. nothing happend after 3-d point.

Comment: First, can you find this line of code (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v4.0.0-alpha.6/modules/History.js#L21) in your `node_modules` and have it log `this.history.location` in the callback (before `this.forceUpdate()`)? If it logs the path that you are simulating a click to, that should verify that the click is getting passed to `history`.

Comment: I did it. It doesn't log anything while testing but in browser it log next object  {pathname: "/kit/base/type-popular-notions", search: "", hash: "", query: null, key: "z33ga5"}

Comment: Alright, so the issue would seem to be that the simulated click is not working. Can you log `to` in the Link component's transition handler (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v4.0.0-alpha.6/modules/Link.js#L50) to verify that the click is actually being sent to your `history` instance.

Comment: I don't get anything when i log 'to'. I also add few more console.log in handleClick method: one before each if statement and one inside each if statement;  only first console log (which is before first if statement) was triggered

Comment: Does your `<Link>` have an `onClick` event attached to it?

Comment: i removed it and tried again. The result was same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133213/discussion-between-pavel-poberezhnyi-and-paul-s).

Comment: Can you include the code for the component that renders the `<Link>`?

Comment: i added code in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133213/discussion-between-pavel-poberezhnyi-and-paul-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Link>` component expects a left click event (`event.button = 0`). The default event passed by enzyme does not include this. You can add an event object to your `simulate` call to properly configure the simulated event.

```
wrap.find('Link')
  .findWhere(n => n.prop('to') === '/kit/user-1/type-created')
  .simulate('click', {
    defaultPrevented: false,
    preventDefault() { this.defaultPrevented = true },
    metaKey: null,
    altKey: null,
    ctrlKey: null,
    shiftKey: null,
    button: 0
  });
```

Comment: Thank you ! You helped me with dozen questions. I'm very happy )